# Vibrate functionality implementing in FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing FCM in my app. I want my device to vibrate and blink led on receiving notification. But it seems to not work as i expected. Is there any way to achieve this with FCM. Here's my code:

```
private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String?) {
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    val channelId = "my_channel_id"
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_icon)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
        .setLights(0, 2000, 500)

    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel =
            NotificationChannel(channelId, "app", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to enable vibrations and lights for the android notifications?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-enable-vibration-and-lights-for-the-android-notifications)

Comment: I followed this article and the vibrate functionality worked for me. Though i'm facing same issue for led lights. Is there any kind of permissions to be added for that to work or am i missing something? Thanks by the way!!

Comment: Glad to know it helped you, sadly i am also stuck with no luck on the led part.